# Tableau Regex calculation to remove duplicate

Tags: regex, tableau-api, regex-group, regexp-replace

I am working in tableau with a field named "product" each of these products have the product name and color in it. For example "Blue Blue Car" or "Wild Yellow Wild Yellow Ball". My problem is that I need the duplicate words removed on the second instance of them. So I would like the above to turn into "Blue Car" and "Wild Yellow Ball" using regex, can someone please help me?

I tried this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE([Product], "(\b\w+\b)(?=\s+\b\1\b)", "")
```

but it only removes the duplicate when they are right beside each other so the "Blue Blue Car" is fixed to "Blue Car" but it doesn't fix "Wild Yellow Wild Yellow Ball" Because they are not right beside each other

Comment: Replace `\s+` with `.+`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, with that it deletes the first appearance of the word, if i want it to be the second occurrence of the word that is deleted how would I do that? For example If I have "red train red" I'd want it to read "red train" and not "train red". Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible with Tableau.

Comment: I think that tableau prep might be able to handle it so I will try to bring it over there! Unless you know the answer to that as well

Answer (score 2):

Can be done like this

```
(\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\b)\s+\1\b
```

replace with Capture group 1

https://regex101.com/r/Gbem1L/1

```
(                             # (1 start)
   \b \w+ 
   (?: \s+ \w+ )*
   \b 
)                             # (1 end)
\s+ 
\1 \b
```

If you have atomic groups available in your regex language,
you can use it to speed up the regex.

```
(\b\w+(?>\s+\w+)*\b)\s+\1\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/0xMVUn/1

Comment: We both misunderstood the question. (See the OP's comment on my answer.) You could possibly generalize your (first) regex to `((\b\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\b)(?:\s+\w+)*)\s+\2\b` (and still replace the match with `$1`), but I don't know if the OP would be happy with the implications. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ptUifh/1)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is meant by "duplicate words removed on the *second* instance of them".

If the duplicate strings are adjacent to one another (e.g., `"Wild Yellow Wild Yellow Ball"`) as opposed to the case where there is intervening text (e.g., `"Wild Yellow Dog Wild Yellow Ball"`), it should not matter which duplicate is removed (e.g., the first instance or last instance of `"Wild Yellow "`), meaning that we can replaces matches of the following regular expression with an empty string:

```
\b((?:\w+ +)+)(?=\1)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k3AvoU/1)

Note that there can be any number of duplicate strings; all but one will be replaced with an empty string. For example, `"Blue Blue Blue Blue Blue Car"` will become, `"Blue Car"`.

The regular expression has the following elements:

```
\b         # match a word boundary
(          # begin capture group 1
  (?:      # begin a non-capture group
    \w+ +  # match >= 1 word characters followed by >= 1 spaces
  )+       # end the non-capture group and execute it >= 1 times
)          # end capture group 1
(?=\1)     # positive lookahead asserts that the contents of capture
           # group 1 follow
```

Comment: Hey Cary, what I mean by the second instance of a duplicate word being deleted instead of the first would be... Say I have "Blue Car Blue" I would want that to turn into Blue Car and not Car Blue so that it matches the rest of the field's format that is already set. If that doesn't make sense I can provide more examples for you!

Comment: More examples would be helpful but you should edit your question and add them there rather than elaborating in comments. Two examples you might consider are "Blue car blue" (a case issue) and "She saw the blue car blue drive into the lake". In the latter case the first duplicated word is "the" so I presume you want, "She saw the blue car blue drive into lake". Correct? While examples are helpful for illustration you also need to clarify your statement of the question. My answer is unrepairable so I will be deleting it.

Comment: @Zr1219 - `Blue Car Blue` -> `Blue Car` introduces a disjointed match sequence that advances the match past the middle text `Car` in order to remove the final `Blue`. This wasn't stipulated. _Car_ is a placeholder for multiple text sub-strings when searching for a second `Blue`. To replace the trailing `Blue` the middle `Car` must be written back. This advances the match position just past `Car`. I hope this is not too confusing. Even if the first pass through the string replaced some text, you cant start from the beginning to do it all again as the string's configuration has changed. Helpful?